# Rails ajax request response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am using Rails CoffeeScript to call an action in my controller, which is fine, but I can not get the response to work. 
I have a form with a list of budget lines. I want to allow the use to add a new line using CoffeeScript so I don't need to reload the question. 
I have got the following in CoffeeScript:

```
  $("button[id^='new_budget_line']").on 'click', (event) ->
    category_id = $(this).attr('name')
    child_economy_id = $('#child_economy_id').val()
    $('#form_id').submit ->
      valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize()
      $.ajax
        type: 'POST'
        url: $(this).attr('action')
        data: valuesToSubmit
        dataType: 'JSON'
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET'
      url: '../child_economy_lines/create_line'
      data:
        child_economy_id: child_economy_id
        category_id: category_id
        cost_type: 'direct'
      dataType: JSON
    }).done (response) ->
      alert "Hey"
      $('#test_append').html("Hey you now!!")
```

And the following in my controller

```
  def create_line
    logger.debug "Hejsa fra create line - category id #{params[:category_id]}"
    @child_economy_line = @child_economy.child_economy_lines.build(:child_economy_category_id => params[:category_id], :cost_type => params[:cost_type])
    if @child_economy_line.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render nothing: true}
        format.json {render :json => "test"}
      end
    end
  end
```

The action in the controller i called fine, and the new line is created, but I can not the actions after the ajax call to work. The part from .done ...

Can anybody help me identify where it is going wrong?

Comment: Suggestions: check in the console and see how your request is being processed to see if JSON or JS headers are being sent.  Not sure if your second 'dataType' attribute is properly lined up or just a formatting error on github.  Another idea is to checkout [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), a gem which may help your use case.

Comment: Hi Ben. Thanks for the help. I turned out to be the missing indent on dataType ;-)